# SQL GROUP BY clause and getting floating point 2 precision on a DATESPAN calculation with AVG

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I currently am trying to find the best way to get a percentage on a column that is a calculation of days between two dates. I then want to find the average.

```
SELECT 
    [Filed1],
    [Field2],
    COUNT(items) AS [Total Items],
    CAST(AVG(
            (DATEDIFF(SECOND,
                    [DateStart],
                    [DateEnd])
            )/36000) 
        )AS DECIMAL(10,2)) [Avg Days]
        FROM [MY DB]
```

I cannot seem to get a accurate 3.5 days or 7.1 days, it only returns integers with two decimals as 5.00, 6.00 and so on. How can I handle a date span calculation, with decimal precision in the average?

Answer (score 2):

Likely, you are facing integer division: because both the division numerator and denominator are integers, the database forces the conversion of the result the division to an integer result.

Many databases implement that behavior - SQL Server is one of them, which I suspect that you are using (you also tagged your question MySQL, but this one doesn't do integer division - and your syntax with square brackets quoting also suggests that).

One way to solve this is to make one of the numbers decimal, like:

```
CAST(
    AVG(DATEDIFF(SECOND, [DateStart], [DateEnd])/36000.00) 
    AS DECIMAL(10,2)
) [Avg Days]
```

Comment: Thanks much, and I understand the int division, but was not sure how to get to decimal from this. Thanks much and will give this a try.